# How to have a flexbox grow to fill the available max-height of a div

Tags: css

Im trying to have multiple child elements of a flex box grow to fill the available height set by the `max-height` parameter, when `flex-direction: column`. This works intuitively with `max-width` and `flex-direction: row` allowing the elements to reflow when I resize the browser within the max-width specified. Here's some simple html which should work given my understanding of flex-box:

```css
.child {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 1px solid #999;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: 1;
}

.vertical_flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='vertical_flexbox'>
  <div class='child'>1</div>
  <div class='child'>2</div>
  <div class='child'>3</div>
</div>
```

Am I missing something obvious? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting flex:1 on the child element will auto-fill the space evenly if the parent has a defined height.

```css
.child {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 1px solid #999;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.vertical_flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='vertical_flexbox'>
  <div class='child'>1</div>
  <div class='child'>2</div>
  <div class='child'>3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the behavior of block elements such as divs, which occupy 100% of width but only the minimum height needed. If you use height:200px instead of max-height you get the display you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> The flex-basis CSS property sets the initial main size of a flex item.

Without the `height` set, this has to be an explicit value, i.e. `px`, `em`, `rem` etc. For your case, you could set `flex-basis` on the children elements to be more than the `max-height`:

```css
.child {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 1px solid #999;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  /* 67 * 3 is > 200 */
  flex-basis: 67px;
}

.vertical_flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='vertical_flexbox'>
  <div class='child'>1</div>
  <div class='child'>2</div>
  <div class='child'>3</div>
</div>
```

This is if you know the exact value of `max-height`. If you don't, you could just set `flex-basis` to an enormous number as a catch-all.

Otherwise, you'd have to set the parents height explicitly, which would then allow you to set `flex-basis: 100%`.

Comment: Thanks, this does allow the child elements to take up all of the vertical space within the flex box. It does not however, allow the child elements to resize themselves if the window is less than 200px tall, is there a method to allow for vertical reflowabilty such as this which you'r eaware of?
Thanks again,

Comment: Just tested it below 200px in the devtools and they do resize